# Rails: Include Model based on column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design, rails-activerecord

Consider the pseudo models:

```
Product  
  id  
  type - enumerable 'book' or 'magazine'  

Book  
  ...attributes  

Magazine  
  ...attributes
```

Where Product has_one Book, Product has_one Magazine, Book belongs_to Product, Book belongs_to Magazine.

How can I choose the Model (Book or Magazine) based off of the Product.type (either book or magazine)?

Is there a better way to do this as Book and Magazine are instances of a Product but have their own very different attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Rails' [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). For example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyable, polymorphic: true
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :product, as: :buyable
end

class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :product, as: :buyable
end
```

Lots more details at the link.

Answer (score 0):

I think bellow code snippet will be helpful for you.

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
 enum type: [:book, :magazine]  
end

class Book < Product
  before_create :set_type

  private 
  def set_type  
   self.type = :book.to_s
  end
end

class Magazine < Product
  before_create :set_type  

  private 
  def set_type  
    self.type = :magazine.to_s
 end  
end
```